# How to decide with duplicate values on column VBA

Tags: vba, duplicates

If I have the following table:

```
Name  | IP      | OS
------+---------+---------
host1 | 1.1.1.1 | Windows
host1 | N/A     | N/A
host1 | 1.1.1.1 | N/A
host1 | N/A     | Windows
```

How can I remove duplicates, and just keep the row with more values?

Output should be like this:

```
Name  | IP      | OS
------+---------+---------
host1 | 1.1.1.1 | Windows
```

I tried `ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1` but it removes all duplicates host1 i.e the result is this

```
Name  | IP      | OS
------+---------+---------
host1 | 1.1.1.1 | Windows
      | N/A     | N/A
      | 1.1.1.1 | N/A
      | N/A     | Windows
```

Comment: The bottom output is correct...those are all unique.

Comment: yes but i wanted to make a macro to return something like this: 

Name | IP | OS

host1 | 1.1.1.1 | Windows

Comment: Can you just delete the rows with N/As?  Will that work?

Comment: It is quite easy, follow these steps. 1)Replace all N/A with empty string 2)Custom sort your table by Name, IP, OS in A to Z order. 3)Starting from bottom to top, delete the row if the value of the cell in Column A is the same with the upper cell. Let me know if you are stuck somewhere.

Comment: What if there are only two lines, one is `N/A,Windows`, another is `1.1.1.1,N/A`. What should be done in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've got so far. Assuming your data is like

### Origin Data

```
Name    IP      OS      Country
host1   1.1.1.1 Windows N/A
host1   1.1.1.1 Windows Taiwan
host1   1.1.1.1 N/A     N/A
host1   N/A     N/A     Taiwan
host2   N/A     Apple   N/A
host2   N/A     Apple   Taiwan
host2   N/A     N/A     Taiwan
host2   1.1.1.1 N/A     N/A
host2   1.1.1.1 Apple   Taiwan
```

### Output

```
Name    IP      OS      Country
host1   1.1.1.1 Windows Taiwan
host2   1.1.1.1 Apple   Taiwan
```

### Code

```
Private Sub test()
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim i, startRow, endRow As Long
        Dim NACount, LessNACount As Integer
        'Set a large enough number
        LessNACount = 1000
        Dim cell As Range
        
        'Assuming Row 1 is title
        startRow = 2
        
        Dim DeleteRange, SameNARange As Range
        'Setting it a dummy range
        Set DeleteRange = .Rows(.Rows.Count)
        
        For i = 2 To .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            NACount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Rows(i), "N/A")
            'Cells with N/A are more than the least row
            If NACount > LessNACount Then
                Set DeleteRange = Union(DeleteRange, .Rows(i))
            'Cells with N/A are equal than the least row
            ElseIf NACount = LessNACount Then
                Set SameNARange = Union(SameNARange, .Rows(i))
            'Cells with N/A are less than the least row, so it becomes the new least row
            Else
                'We have found at least a row, abandon them
                If Not SameNARange Is Nothing Then
                    Set DeleteRange = Union(DeleteRange, SameNARange)
                End If
                Set SameNARange = .Rows(i)
                LessNACount = NACount
            End If
            
            'host1 is done, goes into host2
            If .Range("A" & i).Value <> .Range("A" & i + 1).Value Then
                LessNACount = 1000
                Set SameNARange = Nothing
            End If
        Next i
        
        DeleteRange.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL for the datapull, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT Name, MAX(IIF( ip <> "N/A", ip)) AS ip, MAX(IIF( os <> "N/A", os)) AS os
FROM table
GROUP BY Name
```